# image array - not cycling through all images

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Problem - instead of cycling through the images in the array, it jumps right to the last one.

```
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;

play_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goPlay)

var images = new Array();

images[0] = "1.jpg";
images[1] = "2.jpg";
images[2] = "3.jpg";
images[3] = "4.jpg";
images[4] = "5.jpg";
images[5] = "6.jpg";
images[6] = "7.jpg";
images[7] = "8.jpg";
images[8] = "9.jpg";
images[9] = "10.jpg";

var currentImage:int = 0;

function goPlay(e:MouseEvent):void {
 while (currentImage < 10) {

   loadWindow.source = images[currentImage];
   currentImage++;
   var myTween:Tween = new Tween(loadWindow, "alpha", None.easeOut, 1, 0, 3, true)

}
}
```

Comment: updated code, still not working though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your problem

on goPlay, you cycle through all of them, and end at the last one

essentially you are doing this

```
function goPlay(e:MouseEvent) {
   loadWindow.source = images[0];
   var myTween:Tween = new Tween(loadWindow, "alpha", None.easeOut, 1, 0, 5, true);
   loadWindow.source = images[1];
   var myTween:Tween = new Tween(loadWindow, "alpha", None.easeOut, 1, 0, 5, true);
   loadWindow.source = images[2];
   var myTween:Tween = new Tween(loadWindow, "alpha", None.easeOut, 1, 0, 5, true);
   etc.. 
   loadWindow.source = images[9];
   var myTween:Tween = new Tween(loadWindow, "alpha", None.easeOut, 1, 0, 5, true);
}
```

which becomes

```
function goPlay(e:MouseEvent) {
   loadWindow.source = images[9];
   var myTween:Tween = new Tween(loadWindow, "alpha", None.easeOut, 1, 0, 5, true);
}
```

so every time you click, only the last image gets added

you need to define the variable i outside the function

something like this

```
var _currentImage:int = 0;
function goPlay(e:MouseEvent) {
   currentImage = (currentImage+1)%images.length;
   loadWindow.source = images[currentImage];
   var myTween:Tween = new Tween(loadWindow, "alpha", None.easeOut, 1, 0, 5, true);
}
```

hope it's clear

---

if you want the animation to happen automatically (After pressing the button)...

```
var _currentImage:int = 0;
var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(5000, 0); // 5 seconds
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, switchPics);

function goPlay(e:MouseEvent) {
   myTimer.start();
}

function goStop(e:MouseEvent) {
   myTimer.stop();
}

function switchPics(event:TimerEvent):void {
   currentImage = (currentImage+1)%images.length;
   loadWindow.source = images[currentImage];
   var myTween:Tween = new Tween(loadWindow, "alpha", None.easeOut, 1, 0, 5, true);
}
```

Comment: That looks like it should work but i'm wondering if they wanted the the goPlay() button to cycle through the images like an animation. Rather than clicking each time to cycle through the images.

Comment: Yes, it does need to be like a sideshow - cycling automatically

Comment: *thats why I had it in a loop

Comment: A loop is never executed over multiple frames. A loop is executed between one frame and the next. For example if you had a loop that moved an objects position 1 pixel over to the right, and you had the loop run 550 times, it will not smoothly animate over. It will instantly jump to 550 pixels over in the span of one frame.

Comment: ... so what do I need to do to make it work?  I tried just adding ten extra frames but then I get errors about a null reference.